# How can I make my android app such that whenever it is opened through recent tabs it goes back to main_activity?

Tags: android

I want to make an android app where the user first has to enter the password and then is taken to the subsequent activities.

But the user is able to access the last opened activity through recent apps without entering password.

So I want that every time the app is opened through recent tabs the user gets guided back to the main_activity where he first has to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be to logout the user whenever your other activities go `onPause()`, and then when the activities are created, send them to the password activity if they are logged out.